# Show window dialog from class library project

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class library project already used in my project, I need to show a warning popup window from this class library project.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(
                () =>
                    {
                        Window window1 = new Window();                        
                    });
```

I am getting this error,

*The type or namespace name 'Window' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*
I have added System.Windows namespace but still getting this error. what am I missing?

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
 <PropertyGroup>
   <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
   <AssemblyName>ASSEMBLY NAME</AssemblyName>     
   <AssemblyVersion>1.0.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
   <FileVersion>1.0.0.0</FileVersion>
   <Version>1.0.0</Version>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're taking on this problem from the complete opposite direction that you should. The proper way to have a a library project be able to project a UI element out is not by having the library project know how to do it, but by passing in the method to use as a delegate.

What happens if you're calling this library from a console application, or in an environment where a window cannot possibly be displayed?

Look up how you pass methods into other methods for execution. The brief explanation is the library will define a delegate method that will have a return type (likely `void` for this), and any parameters it will need to take in. For a message window likely a title, and message.

You then use this delegate as a parameter on one or more methods/constructors in your library. Usually in the constructor for the class that may want to display this message, because it's likely to do it in multiple locations.

Finally, in your UI project, you define a method that matches the signature of that delegate. Name is irrelevant, only the parameters and return type matter. That method will have all the code for displaying the message that is proper for the particular UI system. Console would be some `WriteLine()` calls. WinForms would likely use a dialog.

When you pass that method in as the delegate parameter to your library, the library doesn't need to know anything about the libraries/frameworks/classes used in the method. It's simply a pointer to the code that lives in the UI project. When your library calls that method, it's calling back to the UI and saying "Hey, do this thing you told me you know how to do. I don't care how, just do it."

Library projects should *never* be aware of any UI specific elements. As soon as they are, you are breaking a fundamental principle of software development which is separation of concerns. Keeping things separated increases testability, portability, upgradeability, etc.

Comment: I want my main program to be completely cross platform, and use OpenGL and GLFW, and not have any platform-specific dependencies other than some platform-specific .dll's or .so's that I create, which provide a platform-specific implementation for the same header. I can use .dll on Windows, and a .so on Linux, etc. But the main program is platform agnostic. I want a windows-specific .dll that can display an error box for the user, and a Linux-specific .so that can do that, etc. It seems like this should be possible and desirable.

Comment: @Shavais What you're talking about goes well beyond the scope of the question. All I will say is there's a reason that Java being cross platform was such a selling point for developers.

Comment: I suppose that's true. I wonder if it can be done with a C++ DLL that presents a managed wrapper around some unmanaged win32 calls..